Automotive 12 V relay setup with push button switch and multiple devices
Need help with a 12 V Automotive application project.
2 electric motors
1 electric latch/lock assembly
2 push button switch
I built a custom storage compartment with electric motor to automatically open and close, and I added an electric latch/lock assembly that locks when the lid is closed.  The electric motor wiring setup is 2 separate push buttons, one to open and other to close. Each push button must be pressed until the lid opens or closes.
I want to wire the open push button for the electric motors when pressed, simultaneously to trigger the release of the lock/latch assembly,
My concern is when the push button is held for a period (until it fully opens, 7–8 seconds) it can damage the lock/latch assembly.
The lock/latch only needs a quick 12 V power impulse (5–10 amps) to release.
Any ideas or suggestions?

"My concern is when the push button is held for a period (until it fully opens, 7-8 seconds) it can damage the lock/latch assembly." Why is that? There's nothing in the mechanics stopping the lid when opening or something like that? Sounds like a mechanical problem. From an EE point of view, something like a magnet + hall effect sensor could be a way to add a detection mechanism.

Add a limit switch so that the latch motor can only operate when the lid is fully closed.

Link to the lock latch.                                                                             https://www.amazon.com/Premium-Tailgate-Actuator-Compatible-Mercedes-Benz/dp/B09PH111RG?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&psc=1&smid=A31B1NF333K7B
